# Run command when X button is clicked

Tags: button, user-interface, window, maya

Currently I working with maya and I want to execute a command when I close a window.
So far I haven't found any solution to run a command when the windows X button is clicked except to create a custom button and use deleteUI..
Is there a flag or something to so it easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a scriptJob. It will run a process in the background based on your conditions.

```
from pymel.core import *

win = window()
win.show()

def uiDel(ui):
    print ui, "deleted"

scriptJob(uid=[win.name(), "uiDel(win.name())"])
```

Now when the ui is closed, or the X button is pressed, it will print "window1 deleted".